# Add custom class per page on MainContent

Tags: magento2

I would like to add a custom class in the `<main id="maincontent" class="page-main">` the reason I want to do this is because there's a specific pages that need different background color. So let say the home page will be having a background image displayed but when I visit the `About Us` page I need to make that image into a background color instead. I'm not sure how to do this. Also is it possible to use the custom variable or something to accomplish this? I mean I don't know much about magento and it will be a great help if you can teach me the PROPER way to do it.

PS: I don't have any code to share as I don't know where to start. I'm thinking about the default.xml since I have a custom theme. But I'm not sure how to do it in a dynamic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an extra class on the `maincontent` element. Every page has a different class on the `body` element. for example homepage has `cms-index-index`.
Every cms page has `cms-{page-identifier-here}`. A product page has `catalog-product-view`, and so on.
You can do your styling like this:

```
.cms-index-index #maincontent {
    background-color: #FF00FF;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude didn't know that. Really saved me there.